# why can I access this website but other people can't?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, domain-name-system, nginx

The django app at halfcan.org is hosted on an Amazon ec2 micro instance.   I can access it from my computer and from my phone on the same wifi.  But anyone else gets a long wait and then "problem loading page",.  Here is what I know:

- it's not a browser problem: they have tried IE and firefox with the same result
- dns has been set up for a week and is propagated: the A record is set to 50.19.108.242
- 50.19.108.242 is an Amazon elastic IP which is connected to my instance
- the frontend server is nginx and it logs accesses and errors when I connect, but nothing when other people try.
- so it appears the DNS or elastic IP is not working for them, but it is for me.  How can that be?  How do I debug that?

Comment: Are you sure you switched your development environment from development to production via toggling the `DEBUG` value in `settings.py`? It may be that some resources have their path hardcoded to your localhost and not your server's path.

Comment: Answer: the Amazon security group was set wrong.  It was set to only allow access from my IP.

Comment: The site isn't even accessible via 50.19.108.242. Are you sure there's no firewall or similar set up on the instance itself?

Comment: Works now, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Amazon security group settings and see what they say.